# Selenium assertEqual

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assertion

I have created a test case in Selenium WebDriver using the [TestNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG) framework. I am trying to getText() and print it and also use it in Assert.assertEquals().

The problem I am facing is when I run this test case, it is showing error "java.lang.AssertionError: expected [] but found [Register here]" and also nothing prints in the "ab" variable.

#### My test case

```
@Test
public void signinpopup()
{
    driver.get("http://uat.tfc.tv/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login_buttoni")).click();
    String ab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/a")).getText();   // ab variable contains value "Register here"

    System.out.println(ab);
    System.out.println("hello1");
    //Assert.assertEquals("Registe12r here", driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/a")).getText());
    Assert.assertEquals(ab,"Regist5434er here");
}
```

One more thing: When I change the assert condition to `Assert.assertEquals(ab,"Register here");`, it will print the "ab" variable.

What is going on here?

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML code

Comment: When you print the value of ab, what is getting printed? Is it printing the relevant value?

Comment: @ singe31: i have provide the link  http://uat.tfc.tv/.

Comment: @ vinay:  Nothing print. only blank is visible.

Comment: Ya I know the code will run right when i will change it to Assert.assertEquals(ab,"Register here"). But my question is with condition Assert.assertEquals(ab,"Regist5434er here") (assert is FALSE); My code is not printing the line System.out.println(ab);. why?????

Comment: Try to select your link with this xpath `//a[contains(text(),'Register here')]` and it should work

Comment: As others have pointed out, what is with "Register", "Registe12r", and "Regist5434er"? Also, your XPaths are probably causing problems locating the elements. Consider using a more reliable locator strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty clear. The text you are looking for is `Register here` which is indeed found by Selenium.

The question is why did you write `Regist5434er here` in your `assertEquals`.

Just change that line to:

```
assertEquals(ab, "Register here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an assertion failure, because 'ab' has an empty value. This might be because you are not locating the element properly. It is always recommended to use a relative XPath expression rather than an absolute XPath expression to locate the element.